# Mongodb query select performing

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get this result:

```
{
     facebookId: [
     "123123", "321321", "999999"
     ]
}
```

But i get this result:

```
            {
                \"mobileUser\": {
                    \"facebookId\": \"1547339005533880\"
                }
            },
            {
                \"mobileUser\": {
                    \"facebookId\": \"958277234198503\"
                }
            },
            {
                \"mobileUser\": {
                    \"facebookId\": \"10201611922458772\"
                }
            }
```

My model:

```
var roomModelSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        roomId: { type: String, index: true },
            mobileUser: {
                socketId: String,
                facebookId: { type: String, index: true },
                        email: String,
                name: String,
                photoUrl: String,
                genderType: String,
                birthday: Date,
                city: String,
                likeCount: Number,
                insertDate: Date
            },
            insertDate: Date
    })
```

My query is:

```
Room.find({ "roomId": req.query.roomId }).select("mobileUser.facebookId -_id").exec(function(err, users) {
});
```

I'm work on it to know how mongodb query works. Because if i use to build this query in sql it's very easy. I have difficulties to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think about MongoDb in terms of SQL RDBMS, each mongodb document corresponds to row in SQL DB.

So for example if you execute in SQL

```
select * from myTable
```

you will get

```
facebookID    | name  | city
--------------------------------
13453         |  A    | A
2213          |  B    | B
312321        |  C    | C
```

and if you do the simialr query in mongo

```
db.myTable.find({})
```

you will get

```
{facebookId: 13454, name: A, city: A},
{facebookId: 2213, name: B, city: B},
{facebookId: 312321, name: C, city: c},
```

So now if you query for one field and execute in SQL

```
select facebookId from myTable
```

you will get

```
facebookID 
----------
13453     
2213      
312321
```

And in mongoDb, if you execute

```
db.myTable.find({}, {id:false, faceBookId: true})
```

{id:false, faceBookId: true} - correspond to select methods from Mongoose. It specifies what fields should be included in documents

you will get

```
{facebookId: 13454},
{facebookId: 2213},
{facebookId: 312321},
```

If you would like to get these fields from multiple documents and output single document with facebookId field that contains all values, you can use aggregate framework

```
db.myTable.aggregate(
     {$group:{_id:null, facebookId:{$addToSet:'$Name'}}}
)
```

This will return:

```
{
     _id: null,
     facebookId: [
     "13454", "2213", "312321"
     ]
}
```

Comment: how i filter this query??

db.myTable.aggregate(
     {$group:{_id:null, facebookId:{$addToSet:'$Name'}}}
)

Comment: Use match operator http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/ i.e. db.myTable.aggregate( {$match: {"roomId": 112}},
     {$group:{_id:null, facebookId:{$addToSet:'$Name'}}}
)